# what is the difference between HTML comment and JSP comment,For Which purpose we are using JSP comment

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Can Any one give me the answer of my question.I want to know what is the purpose of JSP comment in JSP.

Comment: JSP comment is for server side (Java) code. It won't be visible at all when you right click on browser and select 'View Page Source'.

Answer (score 4):

JSP is compiled into a Java servlet.

HTML is the client side language that that servlet produces after running.

HTML comments can be seen by the browser using "show HTML".

JSP comments are stripped out during the process of compiling the JSP.

So, in short, JSP comments are stripped out by the JSP compiler and HTML comments are served to the browser.

Comment: Note also that JSP expressions inside a HTML comment are evaluated. In particular this may still generate errors if you simply comment out non-working code.

Answer (score 2):

JSP comment is just visible when you see the server side code (.jsp files). It's not visible when you view the generated source, which is displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As its name says, JSP comments are only visible in JSP code. HTML comments are added to the resultant HTML comments, and you don't always to add your commented code or the comments about how your code works in the browser of your users.

Answer (score 0):

JSP comments can be utilized to fulfill many purposes,

1) To help the code review. If necessary comments are written just before the scriplet or any tags which needs some explanation to understand quickly. This would avoid line by line exploration of code while reviewing it for any purpose. But annotations would do the same if it used effectively. 
2)  To omit some lines of code from execution but need to keep the code for any future reference or comparison.

There may be some typical cases like to comment an expression, we need to add some trick.
A normal JSP comment would be like this <%-- Comment --%> and if you need to comment an expression, it can only be done either of these ways,<%--= "Hello world" %> or <% /*= "Hello world" */ %>